# Dagger 2.25 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: dagger/shaded/auto/common/BasicAnnotationProcessor

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

When compile the below in Dagger 2.24 all works fine. However when compiler in Dagger 2.25, it error out stating `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: dagger/shaded/auto/common/BasicAnnotationProcessor`

Did I miss anything?

Note I use

```
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.24"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.24"
    // Change 2.24 to 2.25, the error occurs.
```

```
fun main() {
    val myClass = MyClass()
}

class MyClass {
    @Inject
    lateinit var stringMe: String

    init {
        DaggerMyComponent.create().subComponent().inject(this)
        println(stringMe)
    }
}

@Component
interface MyComponent {
    fun subComponent(): MySubcomponent
//    fun inject(a: MyClass)
}

@Subcomponent(modules = [MeSubModule::class])
interface MySubcomponent {
    fun inject(a: MyClass)
}

@Module
class MeSubModule {
    @Provides
    fun stringMe(): String = "Hi here"
}
```

Comment: File an issue to Dagger 2 as well: https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1642

Comment: Maybe there is a library using another dagger version causing conflicts

Comment: If I used `kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.25"` with above, then there is no error

Comment: Tried `"kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.25"`, doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

It's a Dagger 2 issue. To be fixed in https://github.com/google/dagger/releases/tag/dagger-2.25.2